# Socket.io on Node.JS doesn't work outside localhost

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to deploy a Node.js + Angular application on a server but the socket.io just stop working and I can't receive any data.
Locally was working fine but as soon as I change URL, I can't use socket.io anymore.

**Server side**

```
const app = express();
// socket.io
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://SERVERURL",
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("custom-event", (data) => {
    io.emit("receive-message", data);
  });
});

dotenv.config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use("/users", usersRoutes);
app.use("/auth", authRoutes);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello");
});


mongoose
  .connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL)
  .then(() => {
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));

httpServer.listen(PORT);
```

**Client side**

```
 socket: Socket;
  socketSub = new Subject();
  constructor() {}

  passServer(data: any) {
    this.socket = io('SERVERURL', {
      transports: ['websocket'],
    });
    this.socket.emit('custom-event', data);
  }

  receiveServer() {
    this.socket = io('SERVERURL', {
      transports: ['websocket'],
    });
    this.socket.on('receive-message', (data) => {
      this.socketSub.next(data);
    });
  }
```

The error appears both in Firefox and Chrome. I don't have any particular error message, only:
`GET 400 BAD REQUEST - GET wss://URLSERVER/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket`
and
`Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://URLSERVER`

I'm testing with client-side on localhost and server side deployed on a real server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're server has a self-signed certificate, browsers won't show the dialog to accept the certificate if it's only used in a websocket.

First visit the requested url and accept the certificate warning, and then you can create the secure websocket.

For example if your websocket url is: `wss://urlserver`

then visit:

`https://urlserver`

and accept the certificate warning